# Detection of root and nerves of retinal image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

can anyone tell me what other methods i could use to detect the nerves ?

- or any way by which i could reduce the noise?
- i am new to open cv python.
- In the final output I want to detect the nerves of the retinal image.

This is what I tried so far:

[image: retina_example1]

Comment: no, your turn first, - tell what you tried so far..

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UsU05YYYU44hmCaSSJ3_EspWUK7n_znWfAlZCCFg4iU/edit?usp=sharing
 this is what i have tried up till now

Comment: no, meant to say, please edit your question, and give more details (not links)

Comment: i am new to stack overflow, hence i cant upload an image so i gave that link to show the image.
I have a pgm retinal image and i have to process the image and segment out the nerves of the retina from the image.
I have done is Bilateral filter, Median Blur and then used both Adaptive Mean Thresholding and Adaptive Gaussian Threshhold on the output of median blur.

Comment: k.k. as good as it gets ;)

Comment: @ berak could you please help me out as to how to reduce noise or to use some other strategy?

Comment: Try a [blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection) or even better a [ridge filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_detection)

Comment: Could you make the images plain without the headings etc? We don't want those if we are to load the images and work on them. And yes, you have to provide more details rather than links. Please read this and update you question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 1.added the images to question. 2.what about removing all fragments thinner/smaller then treshold  (segmentate and remove if too small)

Comment: have you tried canny edge detector (or similar?) maybe before an histogram equalisation. also connected component detection could be a choice

Comment: canny wasn't much of a help, still trying.